# Unable to deploy contract (2 lines of code) to chain (ETC)

Tags: evm

Anyone know what causes this contract to not deploy on Ethereum Classic?

```
contract A{
    function b() public returns(uint) {return 4;}    
    uint public c = b();
}
```

Deploying the contract on Ethereum Classic with Remix and Nifty wallet gives the error,

[image]

While it works on the application rescue fork of Ethereum,

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put the part `c = b();` inside a `constructor`?

Comment: That gives the same error, "Internal JSON-RPC error."

contract A{
    function b() public returns(uint) {return 4;}    
    uint public c;
    constructor() public {
        c = b();
    }
}

Comment: What about adding an appropriate `pragma` statement at the top of the file?

Comment: same error,
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract A{
    function b() public returns(uint) {return 4;}    
    uint public c;
    constructor() public {
        c = b();
    }
}

Comment: How about adding `pure` in the declaration of function `b`?

Comment: same error. pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract A{
    function b() public pure returns(uint) {return 4;}    
    uint public c;
    constructor() public {
        c = b();
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum Classic is still on the Byzantium EVM, when I compiled it as Byzantium instead of Constantinople it worked fine. ETC should be on Constantinople in January.